# How to transpose several columns to 1 row

Tags: excel, rows, transpose

I am trying a to prepare some files for uploading into a SQL Database and the issue I have at the moment is the fact that the data in the excel source file is arranged incorrectly

[image: excel file and how i want to see it in the end]

Please check the image

```
CLIENT REGION SKU1 SKU2 SKU3

A       1      100  90   80
```

I need to become

```
CLIENT REGION SKU VALUE

A        1    SKU1  100

A        1    SKU2   90

A        1    SKU3   80
```

Do you know of any method to solve it?

Thanks!

The only method i found it takes long and it's mostly manual work followed by and an index match formula

Comment: transpose is a paste option

Comment: PPM->paste special->here
although it has nothing to do with programming

Comment: Please check the link to see what I need, I will also edit the question. I need to transpose only some columns and then multiply all the rows below to accommodate for the column data

Comment: @lonutt, you can get this done using Power Query(Get Data). There is command called Pivot columns in that which will give you this result.

Comment: FYI I wouldnt really classify this as transposition. I would say this is normalization and transposition is a way to reach it. That misunderstanding is part of the reason your question didnt get the help it needed.

Comment: Thanks @Marcucciboy2, i understand now the issue

@ Gangula i will search more about PowerQuery

Answer (score 1):

Load the data into Excel "Get and Transform", aka Power Query. Select the first two columns, then activate the command to "unpivot other columns" and load the query to a worksheet.

As an added benefit: if the source data changes, all you need to do is refresh the query.